# How can I split a long video into several 5-minute videos on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video-editing

I have an iPhone 12 with iOS 15. How can I split a long video into several 5-minute videos on an iPhone?

I have several long videos. They were recorded with the same iPhone with 4K and 60FPS. I don’t want to cut video myself manually chunk by chunk.